# Change save order of the related objects

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I have a `product` table which is linked to a `product_image` table in a *one-to-many* relations
. On the same table I also have a i18n behavior. Which means another table, product_i18n with the same type of relation, *one-to-many*. I'm using PropelORMPlugin (Propel 1.6). By default it generates the folowing `doSave` method in my `BaseProduct.php` file.

```
protected function doSave(PropelPDO $con)
{
    $affectedRows = 0; // initialize var to track total num of affected rows
    if (!$this->alreadyInSave) {
        $this->alreadyInSave = true;

        // We call the save method on the following object(s) if they
        // were passed to this object by their coresponding set
        // method.  This object relates to these object(s) by a
        // foreign key reference.

        if ($this->aCategory !== null) {
            if ($this->aCategory->isModified() || $this->aCategory->isNew()) {
                $affectedRows += $this->aCategory->save($con);
            }
            $this->setCategory($this->aCategory);
        }

        if ($this->isNew() || $this->isModified()) {
            // persist changes
            if ($this->isNew()) {
                $this->doInsert($con);
            } else {
                $this->doUpdate($con);
            }
            $affectedRows += 1;
            $this->resetModified();
        }

        if ($this->productImagesScheduledForDeletion !== null) {
            if (!$this->productImagesScheduledForDeletion->isEmpty()) {
                ProductImageQuery::create()
                    ->filterByPrimaryKeys($this->productImagesScheduledForDeletion->getPrimaryKeys(false))
                    ->delete($con);
                $this->productImagesScheduledForDeletion = null;
            }
        }

        if ($this->collProductImages !== null) {
            foreach ($this->collProductImages as $referrerFK) {
                if (!$referrerFK->isDeleted()) {
                    $affectedRows += $referrerFK->save($con);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($this->productI18nsScheduledForDeletion !== null) {
            if (!$this->productI18nsScheduledForDeletion->isEmpty()) {
                ProductI18nQuery::create()
                    ->filterByPrimaryKeys($this->productI18nsScheduledForDeletion->getPrimaryKeys(false))
                    ->delete($con);
                $this->productI18nsScheduledForDeletion = null;
            }
        }

        if ($this->collProductI18ns !== null) {
            foreach ($this->collProductI18ns as $referrerFK) {
                if (!$referrerFK->isDeleted()) {
                    $affectedRows += $referrerFK->save($con);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->alreadyInSave = false;

    }

    return $affectedRows;
}
```

I need to access a property of the `ProductI18n` object when saving the in `ProductImage` objects table (when saving a `Product`). The problem is that `ProductI18n` objects are saved **after** the `ProductImage` objects. Meaning that the property is empty when the `Product` is new (because that property is populated when saving a `ProductI18n` object based on some other properties). Is there any way to change how Propel generates the order of the saving of the related objects? Is there any other way to make this work without rewriting the `doSave` method?

Comment: Why do you need to access the ProductI18n object? This is not really within doSave's scope. You should try to do it before calling doSave. Can you trace back a few steps and try to manipulate the ProductI18n object from there?

Comment: I need a property of the ProductI18n object that's only generated when it is saved. Basically a slug, generated from object's name. The problem is that the slug generation code is added by a behaviour in the BaseProductI18n save method. So i cannot change it. I don't have the slug before the behaviour part does its job. I've tried to access the slug in the postSave method and ran into this problem.

Comment: To make it clear the flow is something like this: Product->save -> 1) save ProductImage, 2) save ProductI18n; in ProductImage->save i need the slug of the ProductI18n (for a specific culture) which is generated only at ProductI18n save.

Answer (score 0):

While there may be a trick to getting this to work by reordering the `foreign-key` entries in your schema file, this could be fragile (if someone reorders it again, your code breaks). It may be simpler (if not efficient) to use a `postInsert` hook on the `ProductImage` class and access it's relevant `ProductI18n` entry to get the slug (if it doesn't have it already) and then save the `ProductImage` again.

```
class ProductImage extends BaseProductImage {
  ...
  public function postInsert(PropelPDO $con = null) {
    if (!$this->getSlug()) {
      // get the slug from ProductI18n and update $this, then call ->save();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: `postInsert` on `ProductImage` is being called during `save`. That's still before the `ProductI18n` is saved...

Comment: Hmm... yes, I can see how that might be the case. Perhaps you need to put the `postInsert` hook on the `Product` object itself? Or you can manually save the ProductI18n record before calling save on the other objects.